# Editor shows unseen question marks

Tags: excel, vba, replace, special-characters, vbe

On my Worksheet cell I see text I want, but in the editor it shows question marks.

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0):

This is Ghost character.

Copying a character from sheet's cell and replacing it with Find In Replace, insert the Finder into the corresponding character, do not type in Replace, and the Replace All will remove that character.

Comment: i will try that option, I found a workaround: I created a loop in VBA that takes each time 1 character and deletes it if it ain't one of which i want

Answer (score 0):

You can identify this character using the Immediate pane in VBA, enter the query like:

```
?Asc(ActiveCell)
```

And that should return an integer value. Then, in your code you can do:

```
Const char_code As Long = 63 '<-- Modify based on the output from Immediate window
x = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(char_code), "")
```